# Huawei Ascend P1 USB driver for Windows 7?

Tags: android

My cousin has a Huawei Ascend P1, and he's trying to connect it to his PC (running Windows 7 64 bits) to debug Android apps. The default driver doesn't work as expected, and he has tried a lot of things, but still no solution.
Do you know how to get the Huawei Ascend P1 drivers for Windows 7 (64 bits)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives you all huawei's  drivers : http://androidxda.com/download-huawei-usb-drivers